# PHP session is null when called in other page in safari

Tags: php, session, safari

I have a session created which is null when called from an ajax call on Safari.

```
header.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'this is my session';


mypage.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test']; <-- NOT WORKING ON SAFARI
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that cookies are enabled? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work in other browsers?
Does it work in Safari without AJAX? 
Is this script being loaded from the same domain the original page is on?

Safari apparently has a more [conservative cookie policy than other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/486569#486569). If everything on the PHP-side works, and other browsers work, I would think that Safari is not sending the session cookie back to the server.

Comment: This is generally the case with Safari.  It has an extremely restrictive third-party cookie policy which often inteferes with sessions if you are using iframes.  I'm willing to bet the Ajax call the OP is making might go to a subdomain or different domain, or has some kind of iframe involved.

Comment: I've heard Safari 4 is better, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, session_id() kept changing every refresh, so safari wasn't storing the session id in the cookie. By manually adding:

`setcookie('PHPSESSID', session_id(), 0, '/');`

I got it working.

Comment: Actually there is a more accurate function, which can set session cookie parameters - [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after the `session_start()` in both the files and tell me if the session id it's the same (that means that you are in the same session).

```
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

is it `null` or is it `""`?

when you `if(isset($_SESSION['test']))` does it return true?

is this only safari? if so its your browser settings.

Is your session cookie saves sucessfully and you can read that $_session['test'] in the rest of header.php page?

do you call session_start() at the very very beginning of the page?

do you get any errors? if not - you've deffo got them turned on?