# I can't set session on safari with PHP

Tags: php, session, safari

Session not set on safari
$_SESSION['user_link'] = 'asdasd';
it dosent work
in all browsers are fine but just in safari

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do research on the subject?

> Safari apparently has a more [conservative
>   cookie policy than other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/486569#486569). If everything on the PHP-side
>   works, and other browsers work, I would think that Safari is not
>   sending the session cookie back to the server.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733897/6320082

By manually adding:
setcookie('PHPSESSID', session_id(), 0, '/');

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067122/6320082