# Cookie not accepted on IE when authenticating with Graph API (oauth) - iframe app

Tags: python, oauth, facebook

I started playing with the new graph api with the python sdk.
I'm trying to use the python-sdk in an iframe app to make the authentication (I successfully did it with JS - although the popup is blocked on IE and chrome by default). I'm following this example:

http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py

It works on chrome and firefox, but in safari and IE it only works if I set the cookie permissions in the browser to the lowest possible (which is impractical for average users)

Any ideas ?
Ze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response.headers['P3P'] = 'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'
```

Answer (score 0):

**IE**

Make sure the [P3P](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) header is set on all responses served through the iframe

**Safari**

Don't know. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari) indicate that there is no better way than what you've already figured out.