# Save session parameters in cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, backbone.js

I've got a simple Backbone.js app which uses [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) as a backend. I have a function to log in, that finds a user from the collection, but I don't get how will I save my session. I thought about storing a parameter in cookies that later will be checked on every redirect. Here is my model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        login: '',
        password: '',
        authToken: ''
    }
});
```

And here is my collection:

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',

    // creates a random token
    setToken: function () {
        var rand = function () {
            return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)
        }

        var token = rand() + rand();
        this.set({authToken: token});
    }
});
```

And this is the view with login function

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new UserCollection();
        // template
    }
    // render function omitted

    signIn: function () {
        var login = $('#login').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        /** 
           finds a user within with the values from input fields
           inside the collection 
        */
        if (login && password) {
            this.collection.fetch({
                data: {
                    login: login,
                    password: password
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This function returns me an array with one object that is my requested model. All that I need is to use my `setToken` method and to save this model's `authToken` in cookie so that I could use it elsewhere in app, but I don't actually get how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a model to handle authentication would make more sense than a collection. Keep the model's responsibility simple and scoped to one thing. A model to handle the authentication, then a model to handle calls to other object which needs to be authenticated, not both at once.

I personally based authentication on [Backbone-session](https://github.com/cofounders/backbone-session)'s model.

```
// Using CommonJS
var Session = require('backbone-session');

// Extend from Session to implement your API's behaviour
var Account = Session.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
    signIn: function(opt) {
        opt = opt || {};
        opt.data = _.extend({}, {
            login: opt.login,
            password: opt.password
        }, opt.data);
        return this.fetch(opt);
    },
    signOut: function(opt) { /** handle logout */ },
    getAuthStatus: function() { /** handle refetching if needed */ }
});
```

Which I expose as a service to my application. In this `session` module, I override `Backbone.Sync` to ensure auth for each following calls to the API for any models or collection.

```
var mySession = new Account();


Backbone.sync = (function(syncFn) {
    return function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend,
            error = options.error;

        // Add auth headers
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + mySession.get('authToken'));
            if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        // handle unauthorized error (401)
        options.error = function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (error) error.call(options.context, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
            if (xhr.status === 401) {
                mySession.signOut();
            }
        };

        return syncFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(Backbone.sync);
```

Backbone-session's model uses the local storage as a backend. Its own [`sync` method is overriden](https://github.com/cofounders/backbone-session/blob/master/backbone-session.js) to use the local storage instead of the default `sync` behavior.

> ```
> sync: function(method, model, options) {
>   options = options || {};
>   var url = model.options.url || model.url;
>   var key = _.isFunction(url) ? url() : '' + url;
>   var response;
>   switch (method) {
>     case 'create':
>     case 'update':
>       var data = model.toJSON();
>       var text = JSON.stringify(data);
>       response = localStorage.setItem(key, text);
>       break;
>     case 'delete':
>       response = localStorage.removeItem(key);
>       break;
>     case 'read':
>       response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
>       break;
>   }
>   if (_.isFunction(options.success)) {
>     options.success(response);
>   }
>   return Backbone.$.Deferred()
>     .resolve(response)
>     .promise();
> },
> ```

## Why the local storage?

You could use this implementation and change it minimally to use cookies instead.

The local storage was a better option for me since my API is on another domain and uses CORS to enable public access. [Safari has limitation on cookies.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382904/1218980)

> Safari also blocks cookies from sites that haven't been visited
>   directly. You can see in the security settings. It's default setting
>   is Accept cookies: "Only from sites I visit".