# Setting cross-site cookie on Safari

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, safari, cross-domain

Having two websites: `A` and `B`. I want that the users that open website `B` to get redirected to another website (e.g. `http://example.com`) if they *didn't* visit the website `A`.

To do this I tried to set a cookie on website `B` (by just loading a page on website `A`, setting the cookie). When opening the website `B` I check for that cookie.

This works nice, except on Safari. Safari blocks setting the cookie on website `B`. I searched a lot and found out that Safari blocks the third-party cookies by default.

Another solution to the problem could be using the `Referer` header (when clicking a link on website `A` the referer will be sent to website `B`)–this fails for the users that don't want to get tracked and they disabled the referer header.

Is there a simple solution to this problem, without having a database where we store the ips or something similar?

Here is the code I currently have:

`Website B index.php`:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "visited_first_website";

if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    echo "Visited";
} else {
    $newURL = "https://example.com";
    header('Location: '.$newURL);
}
?>
```

This is running on website A, using `B/set-cookie.js`.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    //iframe.style.display = "none";

    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    var src = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
    var websiteBAddress = src.match(new RegExp("https?://[^/]*"))[0];

    iframe.setAttribute("src", websiteBAddress + "/js/embed.php");
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

The `embed.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "visited_first_website";
$cookie_value = time();
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 2), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what is the simplest workflow to solve this?

I tried to load an image tag too, but it didn't work:

```
<img src="B/js/embed.php">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting cross-domain cookies in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be impossible to achive. Safari only accepts cookies from pages the user has *navigated* to him-/herself.

There was a rather hacky workaround back in 2010 ([source](http://anantgarg.com/2010/02/18/cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/)), but the comments of 2013 and later state that it doesn't work anymore. I tried these things so far:

- The original hack from 2010 (original and some variations).
- Request the page via a post-form-element with the iFrame as target.
- Load a script that initialises the session (sets a cookie) via...

  - img-tag
  - script-tag
  - AJAX-call via jquery

All without any success. I found out that even google maps and analyrics don't set any cookies in Safari.

It might be possible to circumvent the problem by loading a page via link, that sets a cookie and immediatly after that, redirects to the page with the embeded iFrame. I didn't test this method, though because it wouldn't satisfy our needs regarding usability and esthetics. Be cautious about using this when the page with the iFrame is reachable via deep link!