# Outlook add-in and 3rd party login screen not working in (just) Safari

Tags: outlook

We are working on an Outlook add-in (Office 365) that works fine on all clients (desktop, different browsers) except for Safari on a Mac. On Safari our own custom login system does not properly save it's session when navigating between pages in the add-in. It works fine when we view the add-in outside of the Outlook host. Something in the Outlook host must be interfering with maybe the cookies that are saved by our login system. However, if that were true you would expect this to happen on all browsers, not just Safari.

Has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue. Apparently there is something that Safari does differently from most other browsers regarding cookies, and specifically with cookies from within an iFrame(!). While the issue is not exactly the same the workarounds mentioned in the following post do actually seem to work for this issue: [Setting cross-domain cookies in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari). While I'm not exactly sure what we did wrong this solved it for us.