# Safari isn't saving cookies, but Chrome is

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cookies, safari

UPDATE: It's worth mentioning, my website is being loaded via an iframe.

Here's my cookieSession in my app.js:

```
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cookieSession({
  secret: "SECRET_SIGNING_KEY",
  maxAge: 15724800000
}));
```

I then try to set the user, and token when logging in.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){

   Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
      req.session.user = user;
      req.session.token = user.getSessionToken();
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error)
      req.session = null;
      res.render('login');
    });

});
```

This works in Chrome but it doesn't work in Safari.

I've checked the Safari storage via the web console and under my domain there is nothing being saved.

Any reason why it's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting cross-domain cookies in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408582/setting-cross-domain-cookies-in-safari)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you hit a Safari bug here (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3512);
You are redirecting any visiting browser to /dashboard while setting the cookie at the same time, and Safari is ignoring the Set-Cookie header when encountering the 302( or 301 I thing so) HTTP status.
In this case you need keep `user token` in a variable an put it to `/dashboard` controller then recheck and store `user token` in `req.session`.

- Updated: Post your token (genereted by `login` controller) to `dashboard` controller

```js
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard?token=' + user.getSessionToken() + '&user=' + user);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
        req.session = null;
        res.render('login');
    });

});


app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.user && req.query.token) {
        // save for first time
        req.session.user = req.query.user;
        req.session.token = req.query.user;
    }
  // check token in session before go

});
```

Comment: Won't this be a security bug if `User-A` visits `/login` and while being redirected, `User-B` happens to visit `/dashboard`? The global variable will be assigned to whoever happens to visit the page first after someone logs in. In this case, `User-B` will have `User-A`'s session.

Comment: `User-A` has a token string `tokenA` and set redirected will be to `res.redirect('/dashboard?token=tokenA');` in dasboard controller you can get all info of `User-A`

Comment: Looks good now. Also the link to the safari bug is very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you page is loaded in an iframe, the end user may choose to block [Third Party Cookies](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies) which would prevent your website from writing the cookie.

See [Safari Privacy Settings](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph21447?locale=en_US). for more info

Did you try to see if the cookie worked when the page was visited directly instead of an iframe?

Comment: Yes I tried directly and it works fine. The issue is I am required to use an iframe. I am building an app for Shopify Embedded SDK and they require to have it in an iframe.

Comment: Did you try changing your privacy settings to allow 3rd Party Cookies and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah I tried and it seems to work. I just find it an obstacle for users to do so.  Unfortunately I am required by Shopify to use an iFrame to show my site as you can see [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk)

Comment: You might need to break out of the iframe, set the cookie, then redirect back to the original page (in this case, Shopify). Maybe [this](https://github.com/vitr/safari-cookie-in-iframe) will help.

Comment: This is also my issue when developing Shopify App that is embedded.