# P3P issue with IE and iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cookies, p3p

My question is related to the problem outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer).

I have set up my p3p fine as far as I know (the p3p validator doesn't return any errors), but I still get blocked cookies.
The `src` of my `iframe` is an external website, is there anything special I have to do if the cookies I want to accept are coming from an external site?

Here is my p3p.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<META xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/01/P3Pv1">
<!-- Policy Generated by P3PWiz http://www.p3pwiz.com -->
<POLICY-REFERENCES>
  <EXPIRY date="Tue, 16 Feb 2010 08:50:40 -0600"/>
  <POLICY-REF about="/w3c/Policies.xml#Privacy">
    <INCLUDE>/*</INCLUDE>
  </POLICY-REF>
  <POLICY-REF about="/w3c/Policies.xml#WSC">
    <INCLUDE>*/*</INCLUDE>
    <COOKIE-INCLUDE name="*" value="*" domain="*" path="*" />
  </POLICY-REF>
</POLICY-REFERENCES>
</META>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure that you're setting the header right as it is described in the article:

> Send the compact header with responses
>
> I've set the webserver at example.com
> to send the compact header with
> responses, like this:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK  P3P:
> policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP
> COR IVAi IVDi OUR TST" // ... other
> headers and content
>
> policyref is a relative URI to the
> Policy Reference file (which in turn
> references the privacy policies), CP
> is the compact policy representation

As you can see, somebody else had the same problem:

> I was 95% complete, but my header only
> said: P3P: CP="...." and didn't
> include the policyref link, which made
> it work in IE7, but not IE6... works
> good now. Thanks! – AndreasKnudsen May
> 12 at 10:17

I'm also wondering if there is any relation between where the policy file is hosted and where the actual site is hosted.