# URL loads correctly when accessed directly, but not within an iframe in IE8 and Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, safari

I am attempting to mimic a pretty simple feature of Facebook. When you click on a link someone has shared, you're taken to a page that has a Facebook toolbar at the top and the actual page loaded below it within an iframe. The url I'm using has parameters that are being passed, so it ends up being:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/login.php?uname=uname&pw=pw&key=1234"></iframe>
```

If I access the url directly (within the address bar), it works, but if I do so within the iframe, it does not (I'm taken to the site's home page). Firefox, Opera and Chrome function properly, but IE does not and surprisingly, neither does Safari. Now, if I access the url directly and then try the iframe method, IE and Safari behave as expected, but this is not an ideal solution.

Any ideas? I've tried setting src using JS, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with IE IFrame rejecting cookies due to the privacy being lowered. If that's the case, this is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) and you should be able to use the solution found there.