# IE8 and P3P problems again,

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, policy, p3p, compact-policy

Have been browsing across the net, and seems everyone who got into this mess, really slogged to get out of it,... and now my turn!

[IE, P3P, IFrame and blocked cookies (works until page host page has personal information requested)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999534/ie-p3p-iframe-and-blocked-cookies-works-until-page-host-page-has-personal-info)

been reading alot, and i have a very simple p3p policy here: http: // bit.ly/cCyGi5

and corresponding P3P compact policy: 
P3P: CP="COM DEM INT NAV OTC PRE PUR STA NOI DSP COR ADMi DEVi OUR BUS"

1. I have validated my P3P policy via the validator at w3c,
2. I have tried "privacy bird" IE extension, and it says my P3P.xml matches with my privacy settings, and has no conflict,
3. my compact policy matches with my P3P policy, coz some where i read IE7 matches the two!!!
4. If i lower my privacy settings in IE, the cookies get restricted, and if i further lower it to allow all, it gets thru, so it is my P3P compact policy the coz, and needs fixing.

If someone can guide me in the right direction, 
or if i can hire someone for an hour or two to look into it.

M.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that my company ran into was that a site that used P3P was working in IE 6 but not IE 8. The issue turned out to be that the site's doctype had been put inside the `<head>` tag, instead of at the top of the document where it belongs.

It seems that this caused IE 8 to block the cookies that the page was trying to set.

If anyone else is trying to debug this issue, I would recommend following the steps on this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).