# cookie not getting tracked why?

Tags: php, cookies

on one domain i use command as::

setcookie( "cookiename", "cookievalue", time()+86400, "/", "domain1.com" );

on other domain i used a pixel code as

```
<img src="http://domain1.com/?action=trackcookie" width=1 height=1 />
```

that url not able to read cookie , but the same url able to read cookie when it is called directly. when i put htat url as a pixel code on other domain . it is not able to read value.

what might be the problem for this ??

Best Regards,
Satish Kalepu

Hi, Yes I have checked httpwatch and firebug also..

http://www.domain1.com/tracking.php?action=setcookie
that url put cookies:

```
Set-Cookie  topinno=1; expires=Tue, 27-Apr-2010 09:24:16 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie  newkhan=%3A+2010-04-26+14%3A54; expires=Thu, 06-May-2010 09:24:16 GMT; path=/
```

on domain2 this url is called: in a iframe tag..

http://www.domain1.com/tracking.php?leadno=CREATEDLEADNO&city=CITYOFTHELEAD

then those cookies are not coming...

but when i call the same url directly. again i am able to see cookies in request:

```
PHPSESSID=diebgrgusqofs2gckahu2nbm04; topinno=1; newkhan=%3A+2010-04-26+14%3A54; __utma=97007629.526966387.1270733785.1272261298.1272265835.45; __utmz=97007629.1270733785.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Comment: Re your update: Yes? bobince and I explained why that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are per domain based, you couldn't able to do that in another domain.

And If you do it in same domain, `expires after two days` should be `"expires after two days"` you are missing quotes, or it should be numbers in seconds.

Comment: Ofcourse. i used it on same domain ... 1. putting cookie on domain1.com.   putted a pixel code on other domain2.com which loads image from domain1.com ..  but that image request not able to see the cookie..

Comment: Could you debug with firebug? cookie is properly receive / set at client side?

Comment: There's a Firebug/Firefox extension named FireCookie. That might help

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of privacy, many browsers block cookies that come from a different domain to the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers optionally put limitations on ‘third-party cookies’, that is cookies set by resources served from a different hostname than the main page address. Users hate tracking beacons; you should not rely on them always working.

In particular for the default settings of IE, you must [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343%28VS.85%29.aspx) a [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) policy promising to be nice, or the browser will refuse to allow third-party cookies.

[More background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer).