# iframe can't read nor set cookies

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies, iframe

I could not read or set cookie in the iframe using php or javascript.

Both iframe page and parent page are in the same folder and in the same domain.

Last year I had built a site for fun using php / javascript. Unfortunately I had to stop in last September because I had to attend another business.

So up until last year before I stopped, the iframe worked perfectly. It could read and set cookies.

Now I have time again and would like to finish the website. I opened the parent page fine but the iframe didn't work at all. I then tested reading and setting cookies in php and in javacript but failed also.

Is it something to do with P3P? I did a quick search online and it seems it started quite some time ago that if it was the reason, then the iframe would not work last year.

I also found something online. Someone suggested to post this header in php in both parent and iframe pages but I tried and didn't work neither:

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

I will definitely appreciate it if you guys can shed some light on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you're still interested in solving this, but it's the same as the issue described here:
[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer?answertab=votes#tab-top)

In Internet Explorer you can't handle cookies from within an iFrame unless you have specified a P3P document in the header (e.g.: `P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR IVAi IVDi OUR TST"`), because Internet Explorer won't trust the page.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for debugging:

- Check that cookies save on a single
  script in two locations in the
  script.
- Check that cookies work in two
  scripts, without any iframes
  involved.

(Since iframes -are- just pages, you should also encounter the problem in those scenarios.  That will help narrow down for you where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Hi Tchalvak, Thanks for the tip. When I open the iframe page in a regular window, the cookies work fine in both script. That's why I suspect something to do with the page inside iframe.