# Facebook, IE and P3P

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, p3p

For the last few weeks I'm trying to locate a problem with session cookie saving in IE. Our application is running inside an iFrame, so the cookies are considered 3rd party.

I'm aware of the P3P header required by IE 6 and 7, but for some reason I still see many IE6/7 users which never save cookies. I'm also unable to reproduce it on our own machines.

I tried the following P3P header:
CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"

Does anyone knows the exact requirements of IE6/7 for saving 3rd party cookies? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Note: I know that this topic has been disscussed many times, and I've read almost any thread on the subject.

Thanks,
Shlomi Fruchter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one it is working perfect in IE and all other browsers

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```

Comment: You may want to see this terrific answer before will-nilly slapping up P3P yadda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/389458/42574

Comment: Thanks for this incredible answer link. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/05/understanding-internet-explorer-cookie-controls.aspx.