# Facebook Like button issue in IE8

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've got this code for the Facebook like button on an HTML page, taken directly from the FB developer site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FB Like button test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

When I look on Firefox or other non-IE browsers, I see a normal looking Like button, like this:

```
{Like} <[1.5m]
```

However, when I look at the same page on IE8, it doesn't show the like count, it seems to ignore the `width="90"`, and I just end up with a long string like this:

```
{Like} Be the first of your friends to like this.
```

What's going on?

Comment: Two guesses: 1) you're not logged in, or 2) [P3P issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241626/facebook-ie-and-p3p)

Comment: Just in case anyone comes to this page in the future: this was a bug with Facebook.  It is now fixed.