# ASP.Net Session losing after iframe post

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a page and a iframe. Im using this iframe for payment system. I'm sending payment info to moneybookers, after transaction moneybookers navigating a page to our return_url in iframe then session dropping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of another question. For solution, please see this page: [Session Variables not saved when page is in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368750/session-variables-not-saved-when-page-is-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 5):

You could add some logging to the Global.asax in Session and Application events to track what's going on with the user's Session and the Application as a whole.

Also, watch out of you're running in Web Farm mode (multiple IIS threads defined in the application pool) or load balancing

Comment: We are trying another way to do it. Thanks.