# Session problems in asp.net pages within iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have read many SO questions about the session issues within iframe but it doesn't seem to be the exact answer for the problem I'm having.

I have a php site which displays my .aspx sites within iframe. 
In `Default.aspx`, I get data passed from the parent (php) site and store it in a session variable as follows:

```
var c = HttpContext.Current;
string name1 = c.Request.Form["FirstName"];    
string name2 = "Nancy";

Session["name1"] = name1;
Session["name2"] = name2;

lblTest1.Text = "name1 = " + Session["name1"];
lblTest2.Text = "name2 = " + Session["name2"];
```

the print result is:

```
name1 = John
name2 = Nancy
```

The problem is, Session["name1"] loses its value but Sessoin["name2"] still holds its value after postback.

I try to print both names in the next page like this:

```
lblTest1.Text = "name1 = " + Session["name1"];
lblTest2.Text = "name2 = " + Session["name2"];
```

and the result is:

```
name1 = //blank
name2 = Nancy
```

I tried adding this in Session_Start

```
if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = true;
}
```

and also tried [Session Variables not saved when page is in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368750/session-variables-not-saved-when-page-is-in-an-iframe), but this problem occurs in any browsers (IE, FF, Chrome).

The value of name1 comes from the parent site but is it that storing it in a session doesn't work?

Comment: You may have some other bug, like for example this code `c.Request.Form["FirstName"];`  are you sure that you get something there ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting `"John"` from `c.Request.Form["Firstname"]`

Comment: Yes, but you maybe delete it after that, try to add a simple string to see if pass.

Comment: The php site is written by someone else so I can't change the value to pass. Once I get the value I stored it `string name1 = c.Request.Form["FirstName"];`, so even if I delete the value in `c.Request.Form["Firstname"]` shouldn't it be already stored in `name1`? Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding your suggestion..