# Captcha Code not working in IE 8

Tags: php, captcha

I have an order page where people can submit orders to my company.  Before they submit the order, they are required to enter a Captcha code.  This order page is located in a Frames page on my company site.  When the correct code is entered, the order is supposed to be processed, but it is not.  If a wrong code is entered an error message displays at the top of the page indicating a wrong code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message'])) {
echo '<p style="color:red;">'. $_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message'] . '</p>';
unset($_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message']);
}
?>
```

Even when I enter the correct code, it displays the error message.  I can't figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you forgot [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). You should always start with [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) when using sessions:

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message'])) {
echo '<p style="color:red;">'. $_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message'] . '</p>';
unset($_SESSION['wrong_security_code_message']);
}

?>
```

**Update**

I suspect maybe P3P might be the problem => [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer/389458#389458)

Comment: Even with session_start(): it doesn't work.  It works just fine when the order page is not located inside a frame page.  When the page is located inside a frame, it doesn't work.  Could that have something to do with it.  I have to have files inside the directory for the captcha to work.  I would assume those files have to be placed on my company site where I am referencing the order page inside my frames page?

Comment: How about if you replace empty(), by isset() instead?? Could you give us also verbose curl output using `curl -v`

Comment: Are you doing cross domain iframe? Because cookies can't be read because same origin policy.

Comment: Maybe.  The directory where this order page is located is on the server.  On a different server where I have my company website, I have the order page inside a frames page.  Is that causing the problem?

Comment: @John, can't you isolate the code and share a complete sample to test/share locally?? I think same origin policy is too blame.. But I am not sure yet...

Comment: If I test it locally it works just fine, even in a frames page.

Comment: which domains are both iframes. Because locally you should also use different domains if iframes do have different domains. Can I see code online??