# response with a addCookie() and send Redirect()

Tags: servlets, cookies

I have used the following code to set cookie and then redirect.

```
String level=(String) request.getAttribute("level");

 if(level!=null)
 {
  Cookie cookie=new Cookie("level",level);
  cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
  cookie.setPath("http://localhost:8080/saml");

  response.addCookie(cookie);

  response.sendRedirect("http://​localhost:8080/saml/someservices.jsp");
 }
```

This code works fine. But I want to know how? Because when the jsp engine is parsing the jsp code, it will first encounter `addCookie` and the send redirect. Does it add the cookie as soon as the line `response.addCookie(cookie);` ? What if I give it the other way round i.e first `sendRedirect()` and then `addCookie()`? How does the jsp engine see this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cookies are added to the **HTTP response headers**. The redirect is also specified in the headers.  Both get sent back to the client when you send the redirect.

If you reverse the order of `addCookie` and `sendRedirect`, it *might* still work, depending on the exact sequence of events in the underlying servlet container. I wouldn't recommend it, though.

Answer (score -3):

I would be surprised if the code works because the `sendRedirect()` method creates a fresh request and in this process everything in the previous response gets reset meaning that all the cookies will be lost. The new resource `http://​localhost:8080/saml/someservices.jsp` and its associated servlet (if any) will not be able to fetch the cookie called "level".

Comment: Your "surprision" is incorrect. It certainly works as per the HTTP specification.

Comment: I've got this issue under MSIE9 (MSIE receives the cookie but is not sending it with the redirect request). I solved it by adding a P3P header with compact privacy policy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384502/ie9-loses-cookies-after-redirect