# Laravel: share session data over multiple domains

Tags: session, authentication, laravel, cross-domain

I'm building a multi-domain/multi-store ecommerce application in Laravel and would like to keep the user logged in when he or she changes from store to store.

But for as far as I know Laravel's Auth service saves the logged in user in the session and the sessions can't be accessed by other domains.

Is there a way (maybe a package) to achieve this, without leaving my application prone to possible security problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Capture the session id `Session::getId()` in Domain A
2. send the captured session id via HTTP POST to Domain B
3. Access the sent session id in domain B `$sessionid_from_domainA = $_POST['session_from_A']`
4. Set session in domain B `Session::setId($sessionid_from_domainA)`
5. Start Session in domain B `Session::start()`

Comment: I wish it was possible but its not. If its the same laravel installation but with different domains, Once you login to your app from Domain A, you cant send a POST request to itself and start a session.

Comment: I found an easier way to do this, check my answer

Answer (score 5):

If you want to share the session between multiple subdomains in that case you have to set the domain name config/session.php has set the domain name.

Example: if you have new.example.com and test.example.com so you have to set the domain name as example.com

```
'domain'     => env('SESSION_DOMAIN_URL','.example.com')
```

Solutions there worked for me, specifically setting the domain and then clearing my browser cookies & cache.

Comment: Better still just create a .env variable like (SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com). Works for me with on same laravel project.

Comment: Can cookie be issued to specific subdomains only? Such as new.example.com and test.example.com only? and not for other subdomains? To access the session from another Laravel project, do I have to implement the User model again? Should I change my driver to Cookie instead of file?

Comment: I have a little problem with this approach. I use multiple dynamic dns domains. i.e domain1.freemyip.com, domain2.freemyip.com etc

Answer (score 4):

1. On domain A create an image like so `<img src="https://DOMAINB.com/setcookie?id={{ Session::getId() }}" style="display:none;" />`
2. On Domain B create a Route like so:

.

```
Route::get('setcookie', function(){
  Session::setId($_GET['id']);
  Session::start();
  return 'Cookie created';
});`
```

3. Done, Now you should be able to get your user by `$user = Auth::User;`

Comment: For anyone using this, I'm not certain to whether this method is secure, it was how google used to do it, however now they use OAuth

Comment: For simple things that can be stored in a session, this is life saver

Comment: I used this method, the only small change I made was to pass the encrypted session id, instead of the plain id. 

Like this:
`Session::setId(Crypt::decrypt($_GET['id']));`

Also, I ran into an issue on IE9 and below. They require the P3P header to be set in order to have the cookie be set correctly for the other domain.

So I added this line below the Session::start():
`header('P3P: CP="This is not a policy"');`

You can read more about P3P headers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727566/847937).

Comment: @HarryPotts Does session need to be stored in database for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something like that too a single sign-on system, still working to find a solution, but here is a start http://laravel.io/forum/03-14-2014-multiple-domains-how-to-share-login

On laravel you can change the /app/config/session.php driver to cookie

---

Edit:

This is what I have done.

You can share cookie accross domains using pixel images.
For example when you login on domain1.com you want to create a cookie on domain2.com, right after login on domain1.com you need to have something like this

```
<img src="http://www.domain2.com/create-cookie?param=hash">
```

on domain2.com the route above:

1. will check first if a user is logged in

   2. if its not logged in will read the hash (for example email address), check if there is a user with that email, and login it there, also set a cookie

Comment: WARNING: 

Do not send the email over in plain text, This means I could edit the html tag and basically log into any account on the other domain. Encrypt the text using your App Key.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set which domain the session cookies will be registered, and thus have them persist across different sites. Just edit `config/session.php`, in the following section:

```
<?php
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,
?>
```

You're still *restricted to a single top-level domain*, though. So you can have `store1.shops.com` and `store2.shops.com` sharing sessions, but not `myshop.com` and `shopsmart.com`.

If you need something in this format, you'll probably fare better by creating an authentication service, and using access tokens to validate the credentials. You might also give a look at services like [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com/).

Comment: Tested and NOT working. @Chirag answer works though

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what was asked for, but, for development and testing purposes, I did this:

In config/session.php, try changing this line

```
'path' => '/',
```

Into this

```
'path' => '/;SameSite=None; secure',
```

allowed me to authenticate from different domains.

Now, you should be able to write a simple middleware to prevent unwanted hosts. Something like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Closure;

class TrustedHosts{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        //$host = $request->getHost();
        $host = $request->headers->get('origin');
        $enviroment = env('APP_ENV');

        if ( $enviroment == 'development' ) {
            $trustedHosts = array('localhost', 'dev.mydomain.com');
        }
        else {
            $trustedHosts = array('anotherdomain.com', 'mydomain.com');
        }
        
        $isHostTrusted = in_array($host, $trustedHosts);
        
        if ( !$isHostTrusted ) return response("I'm a teapot", 418); //Or any other code and message that you prefer.
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And group it in the middleware group that includes the session stuff.

Comment: Why not just use the config settings that Laravel has provided for this purpose since [version 6.0](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/config/session.php#L159)? (The settings have been there since 5, but according to comments in the file, same-site didn't support the "none" value until 6.)

Comment: It has been some time, but this was a Laravel 5 project, I think. Note that you referenced the 'same_site' key in config, while I used the key 'path';  the  difference is that in laravel, there is a check in place for the "same_site" attribute, while the "path" attribute is added without any check, so I used this hacky workaround to add the SameSite and secure cookies while Laravel didn´t have this feature back then; 'path' => '/;SameSite=None; secure', since this variable is not checked for valid values, you could basically add the entire cookie string there and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer of [Chirag Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335089/1592845). Yo could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in the env entry:

From `/config/session.php`

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']),
```

Then from the app root: `php artisan config:clear` and don't keep attention to warning messages, just be sure at the end you have gotten `Configuration cache cleared!` By this way your app session will work fine on whatever domain you have.