# laravel dynamic session lifetime

Tags: laravel, session

I run multiple websites from a single laravel app. 
Is it possible to have different session lifetimes for them?

E.g. one site should have the standard 2 hours and another should be 1 year

Comment: Looking through the source it seems it reads the config directly... So I'd be interested to see what people can come up with on this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: share session data over multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821648/laravel-share-session-data-over-multiple-domains)

Comment: check also: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/share-session-from-multiple-domains-but-on-same-server

Comment: @AdamKozlowski I do not want to share session between domains. I just want to have different session lifetime values for the different domains

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable for each domain in the .env file:

```
SESSION_LIFE_TIME=160
```

and call this variable in your config file:

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFE_TIME', 120),
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: unfortunately the domain is determined dynamically. i.e. it is not known beforehand and therefore I cannot use env variables.
I would need a way that allows me to set it on the fly with an if condition

Comment: Did you try to create a helper function like
`function getSessionPerDomain(){
switch ($domain){
case ('domain1'):
return 120;
// .. etc.
}
}`
and call it directly in the config ?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can set default laravel session lifetime

config/session.php

```php
'lifetime' => 120
```

2. Create Session_life table in database server and add session lifetime value for particular website.
3. In controller where your login functionality set lifetime comes from table:

```php
$sl = Session_life ::where('website', "www/test1.com")->first();
$defaultSession = $sl->session_value;
$request->session()->put('lifetime', $defaultSession);
config()->set('session.lifetime', $defaultSession);
config(['session.lifetime' =>  $defaultSession]);
```

Here, Session_life is table name, session_value is lifetime value store in table.