# How do i share Laravel session with another PHP application?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I want to be able to share Laravel session with another PHP app(not Laravel), so i can redirect one app to another and still maintaining the same state. Both apps share the same database and i'm host the PHP app on a subdomain. How do i go about it. Thanks

Comment: Try database session driver or something.[reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#configuration) And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26821648/6274211) thread for sharing session cookie. P.S: Not sure about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a POST route on another php app, and send credentials to it with curl for example.