# Why is the session losing values? (MVC3 called from PHP post form on IE9 only)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session variable is lost on RedirectToAction in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562911/session-variable-is-lost-on-redirecttoaction-in-ie)

I'm using MVC3 and the application is called from an external PHP website (form - post).
I've got this:

**Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421 update 9.0.3)**

Home controller - method Index(string A, string B, string C) is called.
*Values are fine and are stored on the session (Session["A"], ...).
Redirect to Login controller.*

Login Controller - method Index() is called.
*Session values are just lost (null)*


**Internet Explorer 8, Chrome & more**

Home controller - method Index(string A, string B, string C) is called.
*Values are fine and are stored on the session (Session["A"], ...). Redirect to Login controller.*

Login Controller - method Index() is called.
*Everything works fine (values are stored on the session)*


**Notes**

This **ONLY** happens when the form is inside a PHP page **on another host** (maybe another OS but can't say for sure) **with IE 9** but while inside our intranet host (IIS) or a cloud host (also IIS) there is no problem at all (even with IE9).

I've created a sample code on the view as bellow:

```
@{
   if (Session != null)
   {
       foreach (var item in Session.Keys)
       {
           ViewContext.Writer.Write(String.Format("{0}<br />", item));
       }
   }
   else
   {
       ViewContext.Writer.Write("Session = null");
   }
}
```

Using IE8, Chrome and others, all keys are there.
But using IE9 there is nothing at all, but the session is not null too. It's just empty.


Any help?

Comment: After a deep search I've managed to find answers to the same problem, as follows:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562911/session-variable-is-lost-on-redirecttoaction-in-ie

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Moderator, please close my question. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found.

After a deep search into google I've found:

[Session variable is lost on RedirectToAction in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562911/session-variable-is-lost-on-redirecttoaction-in-ie)

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Both get into the same core problem. Frames.
After removing the frames from the page variables worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe just tell IE9 to emulate IE8:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: I don't have views so there is no place where I can place this code. Question will be closed because I've managed to find a solution.