# Unable to authorize app: IE-only error on FB.login()

Tags: javascript, facebook

When calling `FB.login()` in IE (any version), the popup auth dialog simply says:

> An error occurred with <appname>. Please try again later.

The call works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.  Reduced test:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '...',
    channelURL : '...',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    oauth      : true,
    xfbml      : false
});

FB.login(...);
```

[Demo here](https://josh3736.net:8/test.html).  It doesn't matter whether a Facebook account is already logged in or not; however, if the logged in Facebook account has *already* authorized the app (so no dialog needs to be shown), then `FB.login()` succeeds in IE and I'm able to call API functions.

---

**Edit**: Trying to authorize the app's admin account in IE yields a little more error detail:

> API Error Code: 191
>
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>
> Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Both Chrome and IE send a `redirect_uri` on *s-static.ak.fbcdn.net*.

IE: `https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f1cd66d36136ac9&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fjosh3736.net%2Ffbec46a30660a9&relation=opener&transport=flash&frame=f1d03767721d88c`

Chrome: `https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f3cc233c94&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fjosh3736.net%3A8%2Ff29e5a7f9&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f1f640e58`

It looks like the JavaScript SDK is dropping the `origin`'s port.  (Chrome has `%3A8%2F` [:8/] at the end of `origin`, IE only has `%2F`  [Reported as a bug.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258868920826496)

Comment: Problem explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Evgeny: This isn't a cookie problem -- the login works if the app is already authorized or if the hosting page is served from port 80.  I tried disabling IE's P3P enforcement (Options > Privacy) with no success.

Comment: What about the application configuration, canvas application urls need to be allows in developers.facebook.com/apps ... and they should NOT redirect to other pages. So check with some online redirection tool if the canvas url redirects or not.

Comment: @Evgeny: Nope.  App URLs are correct, otherwise the call wouldn't work in other browsers.

Comment: Sorry for an off-topic but do you have application running on port **8**?

Comment: @JuicyScripter: Yes, in a dev environment.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is probably why you depicted it on your user picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has [confirmed that this is a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258868920826496) in the SDK, and fixed the problem as of July 2012.

Answer (score 0):

One of the bug submission comments recommended removing the `channelUrl` property in the object your passing to `FB.init()`.

Just a theory, but you might also have success if you include the port number in your `channelURL`, instead of removing it.