# P3P headers for pure html/css/javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, http, cookies, p3p

What P3P headers should I set to prevent IE from blocking
my cookies if they only read and modified by javascript (not by server) 
on my web page (wich is shown in iframe)?

I've tried the following
`IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT`
and also
`IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA`
The headers are set by http server (nginx) for all files retrieved from my domain.
The result looks like this: `P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa PHY ONL COM STA"`.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to read this, especially the part of avoiding lawsuits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Once you've constructed your P3P policy tags properly your header should be set as follows:

```
add_header P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"";
```