# Facebook error 191 - trying to login to facebook -- only with IE 9--

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using v5.4.1.0 of the facebook c# sdk and the 'CS-Canvas-AspNetMvc3-JsSdk' sample.
I edited web.config and set the proper facebook settings:

```
<facebookSettings appId = "290..." appSecret="ba8..."
    canvasPage = "http://apps.facebook.com/itwo..."
    canvasUrl = "http://localhost:3084/"
    secureCanvasUrl = "https://localhost:44301/" />
```

I also configured the facebook app with matching settings.
I can reach the facebook controller: apps.facebook.com/itw0.../facebook
It shows a button labeled '**Login to facebook'**.
When I click on it a new window appears and gives the following error:

> API Error Code: 191  API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application  Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
>   URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

The url displayed in that window shows this value as redirect_uri in its query string:

**...&redirect_uri=https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php**

I spent some time looking into this, but cannot figure out what I am missing.

** **EDIT** **

I had been using IE 9. I just tried with FireFox and Chrome and it works, no changes whatsoever. Just copied the URL from IE and pasted into the other browsers!!! So strange.
Anyone knows why IE 9 fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a privacy token in the header of your webserver's responses.  See [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) for detailed information.

Comment: it'll be a couple of days before I can look into this. As soon as I have a chance to try it out I will update this. Not so urgent anymore since I can use firefox, but I do need to have IE support before going live. Thx!