# My FanGate code on my works outside of FB, but not when viewed within the FB Fan Page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am very new to FB programming and JavaScript as well (a long time ASP.NET programmer). I am trying to use the JavaScript SDK to create a fangate. The page works perfectly when I run my page directly (http://wmssupportforum.com/FacebookPages/FacebookWMSJobs.aspx), but when it is pulled up from within my Fan Page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/WMS-Support-Forum/207356652683205?sk=app_143965989047095), it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't Show my Liked div and hide my UnLiked div, etc.

I have no idea how to debug this from within FB...(when I render it in IE directly from my site, I can debug it, but when I try to debug the Fan Page version, IE's dev tools won't load the script to debug it...it just hangs).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks in advance,
Chad

UPDATE: It looks like the difference is only an issue in IE v9. I don't have the same issues in Firefox or Chrome. So in IE9, pulling my page up on one IE Browser tab directly at the page URL works, but when pulled up through my FB FanPage on another IE tab, it doesn't work...seems like it is hanging as the HTML tab in IE Developer Tools window just says Loading....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a webserver issue. Believe it or not, but by adding in a simple P3P header to your response will solve the IE issue.  See: [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer/389458#389458) and also http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx