# Facebook app doesn't work when Third-Party Cookie is disabled in browser

Tags: facebook, session-cookies

I have developed a facebook app (iframe). It works fine. But when user disables Third-Part Cookies in browser, the app goes into infinite redirection loop.

Please let me know if you need more info to help me out.

Comment: please share some info about what browser you use to produce this problem.

Comment: Hi Philip, Am using chrome, firefox and safari.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you really need cookies? If so, unfortunately there is not really much you can do about this. If your app requires cookies to work, you're going to need the user to support third-party cookies. Check to make sure, though, that you're sending a P3P header. Some browsers require a [valid P3P header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389458/1144454) in order to allow third-party iframe cookies *at all*, even if third-party cookies are enabled.

Exceptions:

- If you only need one request, you can just rely on signed_request.
- You could try using URL-based sessions instead of cookie-based sessions. PHP has some amount of [built-in support](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) for this, but with other languages/frameworks you might have to put some more work in.

I'm guessing that what you are doing is trying to redirect users to the OAuth dialog, and then that dialog is sending users back to your page, right? For that first request after an OAuth dialog, you should try to get authentication information out of the signed_request. Then you might want to store this in a server-side session and pass the ID of that around in either a cookie or query parameters. I believe the PHP and Python SDKs both do something like this. As I said above, if cookies don't work, you will need to figure out another way to persist state as users move around your application.

My honest recommendation? Try to detect if a user's browser does not allow setting a third-party cookie, and if it doesn't, then just throw up an error page explaining that their security settings will not let them use cool apps like yours.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have already implemented the recommendation in your last sentence, but other stakeholders of the project doesn't like that. We believe there must be some ways to fix it, as there are tons of Facebook applications (iframe) and most of them work even when Third-Party cookies are disabled.

Comment: Any app that requires a session is not going to work unless they are passing session IDs around in URLs and POST parameters. Otherwise, they have a very simple app that doesn't need to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

if third party cookie is disable, session will not going to work as well as the session_id is store as cookie as well.