# Passing values through Jquery to an IFRAME in IE 8 fails for first time

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am facing a strange thing in my code.

I have to pass two variables and to display the results of a query on another page through an iframe by clicking on a link.
The Jquery code is here

```
      function showFloorsPlans(flid, aptid){
        $('#floorPlansPop').dialog({
        modal:true,
        title:"Floor Plan Details",
        width:800,
        height:600,
        show: "blind"
        })
    params = "aptid=" + aptid + "&flid=" + flid;
    $('#flpId').attr("src", "showImages.html?" + params);
```

}

This works well in IE 9, Chrome and Firefox. When I tested in IE8, when the iframe is loaded for the first time, its not passing the values in the "params". Once i close the iframe and click the link again, it works..!

Can any one help me on how to fix this?

Many thanks!
Sathish

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with IE not passing the variables in an iFrame due to it's own security settings it seems.
I got the most information from this link:
[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Hope that puts you in the right direction.  It did for me.