# How to have apache only set P3P header on responses?

Tags: apache, http-headers, p3p

So we have a foreign site that's pulling in a cookie and login widget from our domestic site.  Since the foreign site is .de, but our domestic site is .com it treats our login widget request as a third party cookie.  To get around this we're using mod_header in apache 2.2 which works, but it's being set on every request.  We'd like to find a way for it to only be set on responses that are setting cookies.  Below is what we have currently.  Is there any way to narrow it down?

```
Header set P3P 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See our privacy statement here http://www.example.com/example/cms/lang/en/site/products/home/privacy-statement"
```

Comment: _"Since the foreign site is .de, but our domestic site is .com it treats our login widget request as a third party cookie."_ - no, it's a third-party cookie [because it's not the embedding site that sets the cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookie). TLD's don't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need to set up this header on every resource on your external iframe 
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552272/523899) . This resolved the problem I had with P3P also