# Django in iframe in IE, session data not saved/retrieved

Tags: django, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm having an issue in IE (works in chrome and FF) where my site is in an iframe and on a request my code saves something on the session by doing this:

request.session["KEY"] = "VALUE"

However, the next request that occurs does not have the session data saved. Or rather, when I do request.session.get("KEY").....I get None.

I have already made the P3P change to the response as that was a different problem I encountered with CSRF validation. Here's what I am using for my P3P setting:

```
response["P3P"] = 'CP="CAO IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'
```

Thanks for any clues you can give.

Comment: If the page is in an iframe, perhaps the issue is with cookies. The same occurs in Safari, where iframed pages are not allowed to set cookie values IF THE COOKIE IS EMPTY. You could do a test-redirect-initialize-goback cycle to ensure the cookies are initialized for your page

Answer (score 1):

This is IE problem. It is not related to Django.

Have you tried [P3P Potato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475093/969451)? Worked well for me.