# Why does Rails Fail to access the Session in an Ajax request from Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies

I have the following code in my sessions_helper:

```
 def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
 end
```

This let's me call current_user from any controller to get the current User. (I'm using authentication from scratch similar to [Railstutorial's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec-signin_failure) or [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised)).

I have ajax request called `lookup_result` that checks the server to see if a specific result is ready.

```
 $.get("/lookup_result?id=<%=id%>");
```

It goes to the following controller method:

```
def lookup result
  user = current_user 
  # do things with user...
end
```

This usually works fine, but sometimes Rails fails to get the current_user. I suspect the problem is that the cookies or CSRF token fail to get passed through the ajax request on some occasions, but why does it usually work? How do I fix it so it always works?

**Update:**
I don't know how to replicate the error. Only signed-in users are able to access the page that sends that request (though someone could copy the ajax request into another browser that isn't signed in). I report the error with rollbar and save the request data.

This is the usual data for user-agent when current_user fails:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1; ...  )

This implies there's some issue with Internet Explorer sending the session info over Ajax. Anyone know how to fix this?

Below you can see all the data categories it returns, though it's empty for anything with "session" in it.

> Timestamp
>   message.request_data.headers.Accept
>   message.request_data.headers.Accept-Encoding
>   message.request_data.headers.Accept-Language
>   message.request_data.headers.Cf-Connecting-Ip  //(CF stands for cloudflare)
>   message.request_data.headers.Cf-Ipcountry
>   message.request_data.headers.Cf-Ray
>   message.request_data.headers.Cf-Visitor
>   message.request_data.headers.Connection
>   message.request_data.headers.Host
>   message.request_data.headers.User-Agent
>   message.request_data.headers.Version
>   message.request_data.headers.X-Forwarded-For
>   message.request_data.headers.X-Forwarded-Port
>   message.request_data.headers.X-Forwarded-Proto
>   message.request_data.headers.X-Request-Start
>   message.request_data.method
>   message.request_data.params.... //(various parameters are displayed)
>   ...
>   message.request_data.session.defer  //(all these session items are empty)
>   message.request_data.session.domain
>   message.request_data.session.expire_after
>   message.request_data.session.httponly
>   message.request_data.session.id
>   message.request_data.session.path
>   message.request_data.session.renew
>   message.request_data.session.secret
>   message.request_data.session.secure
>   message.request_data.url
>   message.request_data.user_ip
>   server.host

Comment: Please specify the failed time. What request did you send?

Comment: @BillyChan, not sure what you mean, but I added an update. `current_user` fails to return an actual User.

Answer (score 1):

> The error never has any information about the account, IP address or browser.

If user is nil, of course no "account" :)

For IP address and user agent, you should check it with `request.env` object. No matter the user presents or not, the request information is still there.

Comment: I added some info to Rollbar to view the Request information. I now see some errors originating from China, but I still don't know cause..

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be mainly a problem with Internet Explorer. According to other answers on StackOverflow, IE isn't good at passing session info if the URL has underscores in it! I'm going to change the URLs and see if that helps solve the problem. (Though the underscore was not in the domain name.)

[No Session Cookies on Internet Explorer 9 AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350652/no-session-cookies-on-internet-explorer-9-ajax-requests)
[Internet Explorer ignores cookies on some domains (cannot read or set cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794243/internet-explorer-ignores-cookies-on-some-domains-cannot-read-or-set-cookies)

(Update: Not clear if that helped.)