# IE8 block iframe cookies

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have iframe

```
<div id="pool"><iframe src="https://go.eorder.eu/account/index/language/lt"/>
</div>
```

with all browser I can log in to the page but with IE8 not working, IE blocking cookies.

What i try: I try this:

```
<div id="pool"><iframe src="https://go.eorder.eu/account/index/language/lt"/>

<?php header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'); ?>
</div>
```

But still not working.

Comment: Can you self close an iframe tag? Should you not have a </iframe>?

Comment: ok, I close but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this one, its a bit different from your example.

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');
```

Comment: Check out this post:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Wait maybe site in iframe is written not in php ?

Answer (score 1):

The P3P header needs to come from the `go.eorder.eu` server. Sending it on the outer frame will not help the browser accept it.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx for more details.