# IE privacy report, blocking cookies in iframe

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

I have an iframe in a site with a login form. In IE8, I can't log in to the page because IE is blocking my cookies. I found a php solution: `<?php header(‘P3P:CP=”IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT”‘); ?>` but I don't know where to place this code, in the iframe or after/before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your `iframe` or .htaccess file.
See also: [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: If site which is in iframe is writed in c# languogae I must add c header or can php ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The content of header is important :)

Comment: Wait but if this site which is in iframe is not my how I can write p3p policy, I undestand that I only can write for own site.