# box file action does not work in ie

Tags: box-api

We developed new file action for our web-app, it works fine when using chrome or Firefox but on IE we have problems, when trying to understand the issues we noticed that when the message goes to our web-app it doesn't send any cookies including the session cookie although the web-app sends set-cookie header.

why is it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we found the problem, apparently when using iframes in IE cookies are blocked as IE refers to Iframes as third party app, to unblock cookies we should to add privacy policy to the headers using P3P header.

good place to read about is - [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer).

Comment: Yes, I've had this same problem as well, using python/django. My "solution" has been to detect IE and pop the user out of the iframe into a new window, or provide a link to do so. I would be happy to find something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible bug on our end. Can you email us at API AT box.com with specific information about the request that's being sent as well as which version of IE you're using?