# Meteor.js Application does not support IE 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, p3p

We are developing an application using *node.js* and *meteor.js*, this application is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE 10, but when we try to browse this application in IE-9, it doesn't load.

I have investigated the request/response of both browsers (IE9, Firefox) and I have found that for XHR requests, IE 9 uses iframe polling instead of web sockets for data transfer. IE 9 does not maintain the cookies in this case and that causes 401 errors for every XHR request. So the cookie is not being sent in the iframe in IE 9.

I have investigated how we can enable cookies for the iframe, and I have found that we can achieve this using privacy policy platform (p3p). To enable the p3p you will have to add p3p key in response header and privacy.policy file in w3c folder inside the domain folder. I have done all of this.

But things are not working in my case, I have done a lot of R&D to set the different -2 key of p3p. But still facing the issue of loading the application in IE9.

Comment: this might be a wild goose chase, but have you tried using Meteorite(the community supported package manager) and installed the modernizr package? https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/modernizr-meteor this might provide a suitable polyfill for IE9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: @booyaa modernizr is for feature detection and doesn't provide pollyfills.

Comment: Since you are getting authorization errors, is it possible to use auth headers instead of cookies?

Comment: who is still using IE9?

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to get there from here.

But there's support in Flow Router apparently.  Support appears to be package by package.

https ://kadira.io/blog/meteor/flow-router-ie9

UPDATE:  Kadira.io is no more.

Comment: Be careful, this link is hacked, at least the moment I clicked on it, I was redirected to a betting site