# Issue with rending an MVC 4 website inside an iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, azure-web-roles

We have an existing live MVC 4 website that works exactly as it supposed to, running in an Azure Web Role.

A third party want to embed our site in an iFrame on their site (a small part of it anyway, one form really)

I'm no fan of iFrames but this is what they want to do and our business are happy for them to do it.

Except it doesn't seem to work at all.

So I tested it myself with an html page just running on my machine.=, with just an iFrame and a link to the site.

The default page loads fine. It is a forms login screen, when I submit a login, the site crashes into the exception handing and it doesn't provide much useful information.

I then tried pointing the iFrame at the site running in my dev environment. Submitting the login and debugging into the action, the code flows through correctly, no error and tries to return the correct view, but iframe refreshes to the login screen again.

What could be causing this? What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the cookie is probably the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Comment: did u fix the issue. am facing the same. couldnt find solution over net too.

Comment: I used the P3PAttribute class solution in the link above