# Same Domain not loading in IE iFrame if devtools aren't up

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have the weirdest issue with IE9 and below.  This works in ALL other browsers, including super old FireFox.

For a variety of reasons I cant use AJAX to embed some content, so I use an iFrame.

```
<iframe id="formFrame" src="">
```

I then use .ready() event to assign the source of the frame.  The page is on the same domain:

```
jQuery("document").ready( function() {
    jQuery("#formFrame").attr("src","/same/domain/page.jsp?key=val")
});
```

I have tried native Javascript with no luck.

I load this in any browser and everything works swimmingly.  In IE10 the transitions are actually noticeably smoother than -webkit- browsers. In IE8 and IE9 nothing happens, but if I open dev tools and refresh the page then everything works as expected.  The query string doesn't seem to be the problem.

There are no console errors, I have tried a variety of solutions including changing the [!DOCTYPE](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?743000-IE9-Iframes-DOCTYPES-and-You), changing the [privacy policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) (even though its same-domain), etc.

Does opening Devtools put it in quirks mode?  Does the page loaded need to be quirks mode? (although IE10 doesn't like this).  I've tried this on 4 different workstations and IE9 always returns the same result.  I'm seriously stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for a rogue console.log line in your code. IE will choke on those unless dev tools are open.

Comment: Thanks @bfavaretto.  Microsoft should be ashamed.  Make this an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm glad it did the trick. If you don't mind, I'm voting to close as duplicate instead of answering, as many similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: And I didn't know IE10 fixed that, it was about time!

Comment: Yeah go ahead.
Thanks again, a week of hair pulling has been solved.