# save session of page redirect in ie

Tags: php, p3p

i create a login page.
when user submit "username" and "password" if the username and password was true the 
page redirect with
`header("location:home_page.php");`
this code work in firefox but in ie8 doesn't work.
i search and understand that ie has problem with session(that sent with another page, like iframe and popup)
finally i found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) that told me set a header for privacy policy (p3p).
and i set this header but my problem not solve.
please help me.

i use 
`echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="home_page.php";</script>';`
but the problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

Some time I can not discover why header errors appear then i use javascript header instead php like:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="redirectpage";</script>';
```

You can use html meta tag too with php for redirection.