# Why is IE8 blocking cookies from within an iframe?

Tags: iframe, cookies, internet-explorer-8, p3p

I inherited a site and I am trying to make it work in IE8. It works fine in every other browser.

I'm using the following P3P tag that I got from another post:

```
header( "P3P: CP=NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC");
```

If I inspect the headers, it is being sent, so why is IE8 still blocking cookies from within the `iframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code just needs the CP value to contain quotes. For simplicity, I used single quotes for the outer string and double quotes for the value passed back in the header.

```
header( 'P3P: CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't help :(. Any other thoughts on how to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Try the P3P compact header on the outer site too (onlinetraining.php). IE may be blocking the PHPSESSID on the outer page and preventing propagation to the IFRAME.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I look at the blocked cookies, it's only for the site in the iframe.

Unfortunately I don't have access to that main site. I'll see if they're willing to update it. Any other suggestions if they won't?

Comment: I ended up having to change the placement and using header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer for answer why you shouldn't just use headers.