# Session has Expired in IE 10,9,8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, browser

My source application embeds third party application in source application iframe

problem is when i use this scenario in IE 10,9,8 on first request i get **Session has expired** but on consecutive request it works fine. i cant understand what is the issue because in Firefox , Chrome , Safari its working fine and even on IE it working fine but on first request it gives Session has expired error.

**Scenario:**

Source application post form to Third party application and in return i put result in iframe of source application . application is developed in asp.net

can some one help me how can this issue be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers handle cookies differently in iframe situations.  I think [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) probably describes what you're seeing.

Comment: do u have any idea why on first hit i get session expired but on 2nd hit its working fine cookies dont get blocked and no issue? i will look the link provided in comment.