# can't tracking google analytics in an iframe

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I have a site that is commonly included into other sites via an iframe.  I do not care for any analytics from the parent sites.  I want to use Google Analytis within the iframe to track my content.

ie: domain1.com and domain2.com both include an iframe pointing to mydomain.com.

I have google analytics inside the iframed mydomain.com.

In IE8 and IE9, I am running into an issue where the __utm gif doesn't fire.  My assumption is that this is because of third party cookie.

However, I am not trying to connect mydomain.com with domain1.com or domain2.com.  I just want to know whats happening inside my iframe.

Please help.

Comment: The issue only happens in IE 8 & 9 ?

Comment: **In IE8 and IE9, I am running into an issue**, word will be better place without ie.

Comment: I think you need a valid p3p policy for iframe tracking to work with IE (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)