# Iframe not reading cookies in IE while p3p header has been set

Tags: php, .net, internet-explorer, iframe, cookies

I have a php site with an iframe that leads to a .net site, if the user leaves the website we send the user a email that gives them a link that sets a session and a cookie that will allow the user to return to the site with all their details still filled out, we do this by sending the user to a link that leads to a page that is on the .net sites domain and sets a cookie and a session variable and then redirects to the php page that has the .net IFrame

In Chrome and firefox we have no problems what so ever but with IE the cookie and session are not being read, I have read that the now unused p3p policy is still enforced by IE when cookies are used with iframes so I have set content headers through IIS (and tried to set different cp values as well) but this has changed nothing

does anyone have any idea what I could try to get this working with IE? Thanks

**Update**

OK so the p3p headers on the domain setting the cookie (and the domain receiving the cookie as well) is `p3p    CP="NID DSP ALL COR"` and the set cookie header is `Set-Cookie  cookiename=CustId=249674; expires=Wed, 23-Oct-2013 08:29:03 GMT; path=/`  it also seems to pick up the cookie on the cookies section of the network tab when on the php page with the IFrame,but the request that the iframe makes get no cookies

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems IE was having problems with the page contained in the Iframe only being part of a virtual directory in IIS and not actually in the website, when I removed the virtual directory and placed the files within the actual website all IE Problems disappeared, very odd but it works now

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx), then you should share the HTTP response headers that contain both the `Set-Cookie` and the `P3P` header. You can collect these headers with Fiddler or the F12 Developer Tools' Network tab.