# Value from Session is lost in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, session

All!

I've website with multiples idioms. I can select/change idiom in any page. The idiom is saved in Session, if I change idiom, I changed session value.
The problem is:

**If I change my default idiom in Homepage and go to other page, this session value is lost, consequently, this page not translated.
But if I reload this page one or more times, translates current page.
This occur just in Webserver (Pheonix - US). In localhost, session not lost value.**

**This issue occur to any page, but just in IE. To Chrome works correctly.**

Below, my source code to Homepage. To all pages is basically this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //to set default session value. (first time).
        if (Session["idioma"] == null)
        {
            string idioma = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToString();
            Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);
            Session["idioma"] = idioma;
        }

        //if I've other session value (Change Idiom).
        else if (Session["idioma"] != null)
        {
            string idioma = Session["idioma"].ToString();
            Idioma.MudaCultura(idioma);
        }

        lblWelcome.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
        btnRequestAccess.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnRequestAccess");
        btnTickets.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnTickets");
        btnManager.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
        btnManageFolders.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManageFolders");


        IdiomaList.Items.Add("PORTUGUÊS");
        IdiomaList.Items.Add("ENGLISH");
        IdiomaList.Items.Add("ESPAÑOL");

        //Set value that show in DropDown list according to Session value.

        if (Session["idioma"].ToString() == "pt")
        {
            IdiomaList.SelectedValue = "PORTUGUÊS";
        }

        else if (Session["idioma"].ToString() == "en")
        {
            IdiomaList.SelectedValue = "ENGLISH";
        }

        else if (Session["idioma"].ToString() == "es")
        {
            IdiomaList.SelectedValue = "ESPAÑOL";
        }

    }
}

protected void Idioma_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IdiomaList.SelectedValue == "PORTUGUÊS")
    {
        Idioma.MudaCultura("pt");
        Session["idioma"] = "pt";
    }

    else if (IdiomaList.SelectedValue == "ENGLISH")
    {
        Idioma.MudaCultura("en");
        Session["idioma"] = "en";
    }

    else if (IdiomaList.SelectedValue == "ESPAÑOL")
    {
        Idioma.MudaCultura("es");
        Session["idioma"] = "es";
    }

    lblWelcome.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("welcome");
    btnRequestAccess.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnRequestAccess");
    btnTickets.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnTickets");
    btnManager.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManager");
    btnManageFolders.Text = Idioma.RetornaMensagem("btnManageFolders");
}
```

Comment: How do you navigate to other page, i mean using `Response.Redirect` or Button/LinkButton's `PostBackUrl` property?

Comment: I use Botton to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem with IE losing the session each time the page reloads. In my case it was caused by the server having an out of sync timezone which caused the cookies to already be expired when it reached the client. It seems most browsers still work, whereas IE will destroy the cookies when navigating to the next page.

Comment: Yes, can be possible. I'm in São Paulo (BR) and the webserver is in Pheonix (US), and it's occur in Mexico City too. But, why can translate when I reload page one times or more? This means that the session still has value. It's the mistery to me.

Comment: You aren't switching between http and https by any chance?

Comment: No! Now my site use just HTTP. But have plans to add certificate and use https.

Comment: I just found out a fact. Reloading the page, the language changes between the default value and the previously selected value. The correct thing to load the page with only the current value of the session.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a browser setting problem.
to solve this problem you can view as below link.

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

I hope it will helpful to you.