# Can't log in to website within iframe with IE and Chrome. But I can with Safari and FF

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, iframe, cookies, p3p

On both IE and Chrome, if I allow 3rd party cookies from the browser's settings I can login.

However, this isn't a practical solution.

Regarding IE:  Do I need to create a P3P policy and reference it in my iframe website?

Regarding Chrome:  Chrome has always worked fine. Did they change their cookie policy recently?

I have always been able to login to my iframed website. Did anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I've done research and in particular I've tried to follow the process of creating a P3P policy sketched here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer?rq=1). However I couldn't get the IBM policy writer to work. Does anyone have a suggestion where to get a free P3P writer?