# facebook login in a cross-domain iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, cookies, authentication, cross-domain

Note the following 3 files. If all are in the same domain, everything works fine. However, if the parent file is on a different domain, then the facebook cookie does not seem to pass between the two son iframes. I need it to work that way... any advice?

File *zzzfbparent.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="<domain and directory>/zzzfb1.html" style="width:400px; height:200px;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

File *zzzfb1.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="doLogin();"></input>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          status: false,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: false
        });
      };
      (function(){
        if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
        var fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }());
      function doLogin() {
        FB.login(function(respLogin) {
          location.replace('zzzfb2.php');
        }, {scope: 'email'});
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

File *zzzfb2.php*

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php echo '$user='.$user ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question I found a thorough discussion about the problem (which relates to "third party cookies" in Internet Explorer) over here:

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)