# Internet Explorer 11 not saving cookies in jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

Internet Explorer is not saving cookie in jquery plugin

This apparently alerts the string

```
$.cookie('test', 'cookie saved', {
    expires : 30
});

alert($.cookie('test'))
```

But next time the page is opened this is `undefined`

```
alert($.cookie('test'))
```

Have tried to set the `expires` option to `999999999` and completely removed it.. Same result.. Cookie not saved... The string is alerted right after the cookie is set but next time it is undefined

Comment: This should work. Have you got IE settings to allow cookies to be saved?

Comment: yes cookies is enabled.. default settings

Comment: Could IE [P3P Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) be causing the problem?

Comment: Have also removed the expires option.. same result.. cookie not saved.. the cookie is not saved in an ifrme but its on the `top` document

Comment: @clarkk if this is in an iframe, you need to edit the question to add that

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... Have you installed a cookie plug-in? Are you testing in a web server? Does it work with other browsers?

Comment: yes.. The website is `live` on the server and it works in other browsers

Comment: What's the URL? See any messages in IE12's F12 Developer tools console when you enable script debugging?

Comment: When you say "Next time you open the page", do you mean that you close your browser, or close the tab? I'm having a very similar problem, which only manifests when the browser window is closed, but doesn't exist when the tab is closed and a new tab to the page is opened.