# Rails, iframe login doesn't work IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I am using Rails 2.3.5

What I am trying to do is, by using iframe, I am embedding another website's log in screen into my own website.

Problem is starting when I try to "log in" the website inside the iframe. It is working perfectly fine in Chrome and Mozilla bu not in IE (what a surprise).

To be clear: I am able to see the website inside the iframe only thing that I couldn't do is logging in.

Possible problem: I made an extensive research and I learned because the IE doesn't remember my session (doesn't set cookies) I am not able to log in the site inside the iframe.

p.s : using divs probably won't work for me because if I use div and then log in (hit submit button of that website) then I will end up the website inside my div (inside my iframe right now). I need to stay in my own website.

I am going to band my head against the wall, so waiting for you comments.
(please comment if you need to see some code source or sth. else)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a cookie issue, see this question/accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Yes, this is a cookie issue but the link you provided is a highly political solution. What I just did to make it work is "Settings > Internet Options > Privacy > Sites" and then I added the name of the website inside my iframe. That's worked for me

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting to implement it that way, just to imply that cookies may be an issue :-). Just a side note: It is perfectly ok for you to post an answer to this question & accept it if it is no longer an open question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's worked for me:

"Internet Explorer > Settings > Internet Options > Privacy > Sites" and then I added the name of the website inside my iframe, done.