# Added cookies cannot be retrieved from the IE browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpresponse, server-side

I'm writing an asp.net application and I am saving the cookies correctly (stored in internet files). When I open the file it contains: access_token *mylongalphanumberictoken* /domainname (no spaces between them).
The problem is that when I check the client for a cookie, I receive null. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how do i fix it?

```
public void createCookie(string tokenVal)
        {
            authCookie = new HttpCookie("access_token",tokenVal);
            authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(60.00); //Token expires in 60 days
            authCookie.Domain = ServerDomain.Authority;
         }
```

check if the client has cookies like this:

```
          if (Request.Cookies["access_token"] != null)
               {
                  currentCookieStore.authCookie = Request.Cookies["access_token"];
               }
```

EDIT: im using: `currPage.Response.Cookies.Add(newTokenCookie.OauthCookie) ;`
to add the cookies. ServerDomain is the location of my webserver so its machinename.domain

Comment: Could you ensure the cookie is added to the response like `Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);`? What is `ServerDomain`, and where did you access that cookie?

Comment: im using currPage.Response.Cookies.Add(newTokenCookie.OauthCookie) to add the cookies. ServerDomain is the location of my webserver so its machinename.domainname.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add a P3P header to prevent IE from blocking your cookies.
Solution here:

Explanation: [Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

How to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/4f74156a-54a0-468b-8496-85913094fc34/issue-while-adding-http-response-header-to-a-site-hosted-in-azure-web-role-running-with-more-than?forum=windowsazuremanagement