# Transmit Session IDs in URLs (Session trans_sid equivalent Laravel)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, laravel, cookies

We are making microsites using Laravel 5 which are included as Iframe in another webpage.

Internet Explorer has the problem, that session cookies are not working in iframe.

So we developed a quite hacky solution to keep the session IDs in the URLs.

I am wondering if there is a ready-made solution for this (I will post my solution later as answer / make a nice module if there is not already a good solution)

Comment: I am working on a module for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to get your cookies working which you might want to try and might be preferable to putting session IDs in the URL.

[Cookie blocked/not saved in IFRAME in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I made an open source module for this problem:

https://github.com/iMi-digital/laravel-transsid

It hooks into the session service provider and url generator to write / read the session ID to / from the URL.