# How to make use java session when client is opened in Internet Explorer in iframe?

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, iframe

And when it is opened in Internet Explorer in iframe cookie `JSESSIONID` is never sent to server during any request. Thus server session is no used. I found [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389456/cookie-blocked-not-saved-in-iframe-in-internet-explorer) saying IE just blocks cookies for any 
page inside iframe. That is why `JSESSIONID` cookie is not sent to server.
So how to make it possible to continue using java session in IE iframe?

I use jsf and get exception that View myview.xhtml could not be restored.
`javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`.

Exactly on server side I could access

> request.getCookies()

and saw there is no cookie with name `JSESSIONID`.

Therefore session is not assigned to request on server.

Also looking to development tools in IE on Network tab I see that really response has `Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=...` and later request does not have `Cookie JSESSIONID=...`

Comment: please, show your code.

Comment: In first place, why frames? Why not just includes? It's coming from the same server, and thus not an external or non-HTML resource, right?

Answer (score 1):

As the article you pointed out is saying, you need to supply a compact privacy policy in your page so the cookies that are treated as 3rd party by IE will be acceptable.

With your web platform, which I believe is JSP, you can include this line:

```
response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"")
```

Comment: really, it helps. Any text inside header value "CP=\"any text\"" is acceptable. I use it with jsf and after adding such header session cookie are sent from iframe in IE.